# Police selection without hard coding an if statement

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, code-smell

I'm trying to model the security of my project using DDD but I ended up in a dead end.

I have the `User`, `UserA`, and `UserB` classes that were modeled as follows. What changes in practice is that `UserA` objects have an access policy different from `UserB` and for this I thought about using the STRATEGY pattern as a good option.

```
public abstract class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}

public class UserA : User
{
    // custom UserA properties and methods 
}

public class UserB : User
{
    // custom UserB properties and methods
}

public interface IAccessPolice {}

public class EvenAccessPolice : IAccessPolice
{
    // string just for simplify but it is a Service
    private readonly string _someDependencyInjected;

    public EvenAccessPolice(string someDependencyInjected)
    {
        _someDependencyInjected = someDependencyInjected;
    }

    public bool CanAccess(UserA user)
    {
        // authentication logic for UserA
        return user.UserId % 2 == 0;
    }
}

public class OddAccessPolice : IAccessPolice
{
    public bool CanAccess(UserB user)
    {
        // authentication logic for UserB
        return user.UserId % 2 != 0;
    }
}

public class AuthenticationService
{
    public IList<User> _userRepository = new List<User>();

    public bool CheckIfUserCanLogin(int userId)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

        // this if is annoing me
        if (user is UserA)
        {
            var authPolice = new EvenAccessPolice("Inject this value...");
            return authPolice.CanAccess(user as UserA);
        }
        else
        {
            var authPolice = new OddAccessPolice();
            return authPolice.CanAccess(user as UserB);
        }
    }
}
```

`AuthenticationService` gets the user instance (`UserA` or `UserB`) and checks whether or not the user can access the system. The `if` statement used to decide which of the policies should be executed is a code smell to me since my service will not be closed when I'll have to add/change the polices.

Because the policy is tied to the `user` subtype, I thought of putting a property in `UserA` and `UserB` that would return the correct instance of `IAccessPolice`, but that would force me to load the `EvenAccessPolice` dependencies into my domain entity, and I think that's not an option (code smell).

Is there some way to acquire the `IAccessPolice` from `user` without use of an `if` statement?

Comment: use a dictionary of IAccessPolice keyed on type

Comment: Why doesn't the IAccessPolice interface define a method of `bool CanAccess(User user)`?  That's part of the strategy pattern so that you can look up instances keyed on type, use a factory, or use dependency injection to get the appropriate instance--and then you can simply call the policy's `CanAccess` method.

Comment: @Ewan, If the method were the same he could do that.  Unfortunately, by limiting the `CanAccess` call to subtypes, he's still forced to have an if statement to make the right cast.  He needs to fix the interface first.

Answer (score 5):

The key issue here is that your policy interface has no methods.  It has no purpose other than to mark classes.  In order to make the policy agnostic, you need to define the `CanAccess` method in the interface.  It would look like this:

```
public interface IAccessPolice
{
    bool CanAccess(User user);
}
```

This keeps the interface the same for your even and odd policies so that your `AuthenticationService` doesn't need to know the details of the instance.  Once you do that, you can use many different strategies to get the `IAccessPolice` that is appropriate for your user.  One option is to inject it into your `User`:

```
public abstract class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public IAccessPolice AccessPolice { get; private set; } // readonly
}
```

Another option is to have your `IAuthenticationService` use a factory pattern to create or lookup the appropriate `IAccessPolice` instance:

```
public class AuthenticationService
{
    // ... all the other stuff

    private IAccessPolice GetAccessPoliceForUser (User user)
    {
        // Create or lookup based on type,
        // or simply pull it from the user instance
        // if you injected it into your user above:

        return user.AccessPolice;
    }
}
```

In either case, it simplifies the method you are concerned about to work in this way:

```
public bool CheckIfUserCanLogin(int userId)
{
    var user = _userRepository.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    var accessPolice = GetAccessPoliceForUser(user);

    return accessPolice.CanAccess(user);
}
```

Comment: I've considered do this but I didn't like to have the dependency of EvenAccessPolice carried to the User. Anyway You gave me a clu, I thought again and I'll change the polices implementation in order to give its dependencies just before return the instance by the factory. It isn't the most charming option but solves the if and the depency code smells.

Comment: The critical part is that your interface is not specific to a user type.  Feel free to initialize a dictionary with the type as the key to retrieve your implementation, and access it from the factory/accessor method.  Don't feel compelled to keep the instance in the `User` if that is something you want to avoid.